# What effect does an increase in concentration of copper sulphate solution have on the rate at which copper is deposited at the cathode?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, electrochemistry, kinetics, electrolysis

I have been studying electrolysis in school and was wondering whether a higher amount of copper sulfate solution would produce a greater mass of copper in an electrolytic cell with two copper electrodes in a given amount of time or not.

Comment: No, the amount of copper deposited is dependent on the current passed (unless you actually run out of copper in solution)